# Arraylist of Hashmap replacement of particular index

Tags: java, android, arraylist, replace, hashmap

Hi I am trying to replace the particular index of the arraylist which contains hashmap.Here is the code I am trying to get it,

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vehiclehistory = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
```

Adding values to the map and arraylist,

```
 for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
 map.put(TAG_Latitude + i, latitude);
 map.put(TAG_Longitude + i, longitude);
 map.put(TAG_Speed + i, speed);
 map.put(TAG_Vehicle_Status + i, sleepstring);
 vehiclehistory.add(i, map);
 }
```

I am expecting to add individual map at particular index like,

```
map adding::{address0=965, ECR Link Road, VGP Prabhu Nagar, Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600100, India, latitude0=12.906466666667, longitude0=80.204440000000, speed0=0, bus_tracking_timestamp0=2014-12-08 10:36:01, vehicle_status0=1, exceed_speed_limit0=0}

map adding::{address1=965, ECR Link Road, VGP Prabhu Nagar, Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600100, India, latitude1=12.906466666667, longitude1=80.204440000000, speed1=0, bus_tracking_timestamp1=2014-12-08 10:36:01, vehicle_status1=1, exceed_speed_limit1=0}
```

But it adding like,

```
map adding::{exceed_speed_limit1=0, exceed_speed_limit0=0, address0=965, ECR Link Road, VGP 
Prabhu Nagar, Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600100, India, address1=965, ECR Link Road, VGP  
Prabhu Nagar, Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600100, India, bus_tracking_timestamp1=2014-12-08 
10:36:32, bus_tracking_timestamp0=2014-12-08 10:36:01, latitude0=12.906466666667, 
latitude1=12.906466666667, vehicle_status1=1, speed1=0, longitude0=80.204440000000, 
longitude1=80.204440000000, speed0=0, vehicle_status0=1}
```

Maps are appending itself and my arraylist looks like,

```
 12-11 10:16:15.291: I/System.out(28913): history list val::[{exceed_speed_limit1=0, 
 exceed_speed_limit0=0, address0=965, ECR Link Road, VGP Prabhu Nagar, Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil   
 Nadu 600100, India, address1=965, ECR Link Road, VGP Prabhu Nagar, Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil 
 00100, India, bus_tracking_timestamp1=2014-12-08 10:36:32, bus_tracking_timestamp0=2014-12-08 
 10:36:01, latitude0=12.906466666667, latitude1=12.906466666667, vehicle_status1=1, speed1=0, 
 longitude0=80.204440000000, longitude1=80.204440000000, speed0=0, vehicle_status0=1},
 {exceed_speed_limit1=0, exceed_speed_limit0=0, address0=965, ECR Link Road, VGP Prabhu Nagar,
 Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600100, India, address1=965, ECR Link Road, VGP Prabhu Nagar,
 Medavakkam, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600100, India, bus_tracking_timestamp1=2014-12-08 10:36:32, 
 bus_tracking_timestamp0=2014-12-08 10:36:01, latitude0=12.906466666667,     
 latitude1=12.906466666667, vehicle_status1=1, speed1=0, longitude0=80.204440000000,  
 longitude1=80.204440000000, speed0=0,vehicle_status0=1}]
```

Can anyone tell how to add hashmap values specifically to arraylist and replace the specific index of arraylist with particular some map values?

Comment: HashMap<String, VehicleHistoryObject> map = new HashMap<String, VehicleHistoryObject>();

i think this will be better approach to put all your object to hash map and use any key to retrieve them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're adding the same `map` to the `ArrayList` each time. You need to make a new `HashMap` instance and populate it each iteration, like so:

```
HashMap<String, String> map = null;

for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
    map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    map.put(TAG_Latitude + i, latitude);
    map.put(TAG_Longitude + i, longitude);
    map.put(TAG_Speed + i, speed);
    map.put(TAG_Vehicle_Status + i, sleepstring);

    vehiclehistory.add(i, map);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After add the all data in Array list,You want to change the particular index means, try this.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vehiclehistory = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map = vehiclehistory.get(index);
map.put("key_name", "string");
```

Answer (score 1):

you have created hashmap only once and adding that same hashmap to your ararylist that is causing the problem do it like this:-

```
 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> vehiclehistory = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 HashMap<String, String> map =null;

for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
map = new HashMap<String, String>();

map.put(TAG_Latitude + i, latitude);
map.put(TAG_Longitude + i, longitude);
map.put(TAG_Speed + i, speed);
map.put(TAG_Vehicle_Status + i, sleepstring);
vehiclehistory.add(i, map);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try with this...**

**Declare as Global Variable**

```
Map<String, String> myLatLongHashMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
int k = 0;
```

**Assign Hashmap values**

```
    myLatLongHashMap.put("lat" + k, latvalue);
    myLatLongHashMap.put("long" + k, longvalue);
    myLatLongHashMap.put("TAG_Speed" + k, TAG_Speed_value+"");
    k++;
```

**Retrieve Hashmap values**

```
  if (myLatLongHashMap.size() > 0)
  {
    for (int i = 0; i < myLatLongHashMap.size() / 3; i++)
    {
         // retrieve your lat, long value..
      Double lat   =   Double.valueOf(myLatLongHashMap.get("lat" + i)); 
      Double longg  =   Double.valueOf(myLatLongHashMap.get("long" + i));
      String speed =   myLatLongHashMap.get("TAG_Speed" + i);
    }
  }
```